# Disqus commenting - show latest comments first

Tags: javascript, disqus

How to display Disqus showing the newest comments first, rather than the highest ranked ones?

Programatically, to show it by default.

Comment: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466213-sorting-comments

Comment: @marmeladze I mean programatally, so it will be by default. Sorry for not being clear, I update the question.